# TYPO3: RTE htmlArea move cursor in IE during work with custom styles

Tags: internet-explorer, html-lists, typo3, rte

I have got a strange behaviour on a TYPO3 based website. When I'm logged into the backend of the site and try to edit a certain block element of a text part, Internet Explorer displays the move cursor while on mouse over. In this very case it's a li - element which was previously styled with a custom style. Once the parent ul - element gets its special class (this happens by selecting the appripriate block style in the drop down) IE drives itself crazy.

I already tried to get rid of this by activating al kinds of TSConfig properties. But nothing appeared to help up until now.

The settings

```
disableAlignmentFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
disableSpacingFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
disableColorFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
disableLayoutFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
disableBordersFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
## Show borders on table creation
buttons.toggleborders.setOnTableCreation = 1
```

did not help so far.

Is there somebody out there having the same or a similar issue? How did you get rid of that?

Thanks a lot.
siorpaesas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's your case but this behavior can happen due to some attributes in the CSS file that is loaded by the htmlArea: `RTE.default.contentCSS`

I'm not able to tell you in which versions of IE this can happen (I can reproduce it in IE 7) and I don't know all the attributes that might cause this but I know that for example `min-height` might trigger this.

So start with debugging the CSS by removing atttributes from it. **Make sure the browser loads the new version of the file after each change and before the content with the RTE is opened again!** (open the file in a new tab to check the content that the browser uses)

Comment: Hey cascaval

Thank you very much for your input. 
I first thought my CSS would be correct and it would not matter if it looked the same as in the front end of the site. 
But then I realized that a specified width - property in CSS could make the IE go on a rampage. After removing it, it worked smoothly.

Comment: Yeah, I think it might be all the attributes that set dimensions.

Comment: The quintessence of this: Never use width or height properties during specification of custom CSS classes in the backend!